# How to bulk delete specific documents from Firestore in Python

Tags: python, io, google-cloud-firestore, multiprocessing

If I have a list of document IDs and I want to delete them from firestore what is the most efficient method to do so? I'm currently using a loop over the list:

```
document_ids = ["xyz123", "abc0987", "tvu765", ...] # could be up to 30 IDs

for id in document_ids:
   database.collection("documents").document(id).delete()
```

This is done via an AJAX call from the frontend to a Flask route, once it's done it sends back a response, but when theres 20+ id's it can take a few seconds to complete the process.

Is there a way to say, here, delete these from this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `multiprocessing` to speed-up the io-bound operations.

## Use Multiprocessing To Speed Up

[Refer: YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/fKl2JW_qrso?t=1012)

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
from google.cloud import firestore

document_ids = ["xyz123", "abc0987", "tvu765", ...] # could be up to 30 IDs
def delete_doc(doc_id):
    database = firestore.Client() 
    database.collection("documents").document(doc_id).delete()

t_start = time.perf_counter()
processes = list()
for id in document_ids:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=delete_doc, args=[id,])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()

t_finish = time.perf_counter()

print("Total Elapsed Time: {} s".format(round(t_finish - t_start, 3)))
```

Comment: @Ari Please let me know if this worked or not. Since I do not have access to a similar set up, it was not possible for me to run a proper test.

Comment: Yes this worked! I had to make some changes but basically 99% was your code, thanks a lot

Comment: Be aware that this will not scale up very high.  Since this is creating a new process for each document, and kicking them all off at the same time, it's going to be gated by the amount of memory available on the system.  A new process could be fairly large, and the machine could churn, making everything run much slower.

Comment: @DougStevenson this is true, could I limit this? if I'm giving it 30 id's will it potentially try 30 processes? can I batch it say 4 or so at a time?

Comment: You could definitely batch the IDs to limit the maximum amount of memory consumption.

Comment: Okay ill experiment, I do know what you mean though, I've tried something similar before and I get an exception because of the number of queries happening at once

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right now is pretty much the only way.  There is no SQL-like "delete from ... where ..." command.  You have to delete each document using its ID.

Comment: That sounds like decent performance. But as Doug said, there is no "conditional delete" operation, so you're firing 1,000 individual delete operations, which is the correct approach (and quite fast indeed).